# How do I create a JavaScript file that opens another file and prints the content of it?

Tags: javascript, windows, file, jsp

I am using JavaScript locally on a Windows computer.  In the folder that I put this .jsp file, I have a file named text.txt.  I want this .jsp file to display the content of the file.  It is as if my function is never invoked.  I use a web browser to test the script.  I see "JavaScript locally on Windows" as my header shows.  What should I do to get my function to work?  I get no error message.  I searched the internet.  I based my code off of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file).

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Javascript locally on Windows </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<h2>JavaScript locally on Windows</h2>

<script language="Javascript">


function readContentOfFile(file)
{
    var inputFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    inputFile.open("GET", file, false);
    inputFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(inputFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(inputFile.status === 200 || inputFile.status == 0)
            {
                var contentText = inputFile.responseText;
                alert(contentText);
            }
        }
    }
    inputFile.send(null);
}


readContentOfFile(text.txt)

</script>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: check the developer tools console for any errors

Comment: This might not be completely relevant but have you looked into using nodejs instead.

Comment: First of all, the parameter you passed to 'readContentOfFile' is not a string and must be undefined. But like @JaromandaX said, without the error, we can't be of any help

Answer (score 2):

The error is when you pass the file name as parameter to the function.

Watch for:

```
inputFile.open("GET", file, false);
```

**open**  is a method of the XMLHttpRequest object that expects the second parameter as a string.
Because you define this variable on the function parameter here:

```
function readContentOfFile(file)
```

You should pass the parameter as a string wrapping it in quotes:

```
readContentOfFile("text.txt")
```